# If Statement in Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have this in my Visual Studio Project

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Compiling TypeScript files" />
    <Message Text="Executing tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
    <Exec Command="tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

I want to execute the stuff within the `<Target Name="BeforeBuild"></Target>` if the Configuration is Debug and the Platform is AnyCPU.  Is this possible and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'">
```

Slightly more fancy version

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
```

Comment: @SachinKainth oops, had to update my answer because i had the casing on AnyCPU wrong (i had the CPU as lower case)